# Print specific line in python?

Tags: python, file, printing

I have got this code so far.
You input a number and it should read the specific line in the `packages.txt` file and print it into the python shell.In the code below, if you enter "3" in for example it will print line 1-3 which i do not want it to do.

`which = input('Which package would you like?: ')`

```
    with open('packages.txt') as f:
        i = 0
        for line in f:
            if i == (int(which)):
                break
            i += 1
            print (line)
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* it prints lines 1-3? (If you can, then you are a good way to solving the problem! :) )

Comment: I think that python maybe reads line 0 to (which) and prints them? or am i wrong here? :P

Comment: Yes, that is *what* happens, but why does that happen? (Which part of the code means that every line up to `which` is printed? Where does Python iterate through the lines and where does the print statement occur?)

Comment: well, you input a number, i gets set to that number and it will print until f is set to 0? i think that the problem occurs in "i += 1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the flow of the code and when `print (line)` is being called.

Can you see the 2 *very* important differences between this code and yours?

```
which = input('Which package would you like?: ')

with open('packages.txt') as f:
    i = 1
    for line in f:
        if i == (int(which)):
            break
        i += 1
print (line)
```

Comment: `f` doesn't change at all, it's the file.  `i` is changing, that's what the line `i += 1` does, it adds 1 to the value of `i`.

Comment: i think the problem is at i += 1?

Comment: Nope, that line is fine, we are reading through the file `f` one line at a time.  `i` is keeping track of which line we are on.

Comment: you changed the i to = 1 and you moved the print

Comment: oh i get it now, i is the line it is reading, so when the program starts running it will start by reading line 1? and then set it to the (which)?

Comment: `for` is a loop, meaning it repeats.  If you put the `print` tabbed in  below the `for` that means every time we go through the loop, the print will happen.  However, we only want to print once, and we want that print to happen after we get to the line the user put into the `which` variable.

Comment: The reading takes place independent of our counting.  That's what `with` does.  We are just using the `i` variable to keep track of where we are.  When we get to the right line (when our counter is the same as the `which` variable) we `break`.  Then outside the `for` and outside the `with` we `print`.

Comment: can i be changed to something else? like "track"?

Comment: You can change to just about anything you want, as long as you change it everywhere, and don't use a python keyword like `for`.  `track`, `counter` or `line_number`are good choices.

Comment: Also, `i += 1` is just shorthand for `i = i + 1`, meaning we are incrementing `i`.  In some languages they shorten it even further to `i++` I guess because it's such a common operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can `enumerate` over `f` to get the index of a line and print it if it matches `which`. I assumed this is a homework question, so not putting complete code here :)

Comment: Nah this is not a homework question, i am trying to make a little calculator for my website :P

Comment: would changing i += 1 to i += (which) help?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

`lines = open('packages.txt').readlines()`

Now you can guess the rest of it.